# How can I thicken the underline on a MaterialUI <Link>?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

looking for a way to increase the thickness of a Material UI `<Link>`

on some of the MUI elements they have InputProps (for text boxes for example) so you can style the internal elements. cant find anything for the

textDecorationThickness

property on the `<Link>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of one way to increase the thickness:

```
const Link = withStyles({
  root: {
    "&:hover": { textDecorationThickness: "3px" }
  }
})(MuiLink);
```

[image: Edit Link underline thickness]

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-thickness
- https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.11.4/packages/material-ui/src/Link/Link.js#L22

Comment: i did it in my theme file. this works too. thanks +1